# Laravel Task Scheduling with multiple kernel.php like files

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have a fully functional laravel scheduling system which I list my jobs and codes under app/Console/Kernel.php

the problem I face is that sometimes our teammates put some codes which cause the scheduling to crush and finally cause prevention of important jobs' execution.

I was thinking if there was a way to have multiple Kernel.php like files, to put some important jobs to one, and the new ones which may cause problems to another.

Thanks

Comment: What are the sort of things your teammates add? Do you have tests set up for you scheduling tasks?

Comment: @RossWilson any kind of crashing code. no I don't have tests for it, how do I do it?

Comment: Having another file doesn't do much to limit breaking changes. Running your scheduled commands asynchronously if possible would do a lot more to help with other people's code; since their command would run in a separate process, a Queued Job would be good. Moving your code into Jobs may require a good amount of work for you, but I think that's a better architecture in general.